# Fastest time between two points by walking under some constraints

Tags: optimization

> [image]

So the problem, is that I want to walk A to B under the fastest time. If I had no constraints, then the answer is simple, simply a straight line from A to B but here I have some constraint which makes it complicated.

**Here are my rules and set up:**
I can make along the purple path from A to B, but I can also move in the region enclosed by ABC in the following ways:

1. I can move a 'step' to the right (however steps crossing BC is not allowed)
2. Similarly I can step directly in the direction of B
3. I can take a step 'up' so I get closed to AB (though I can never cross it)

You may take step size as large or small as you want.

I want to rigorously prove that for any sequence of the three steps I have described above which terminates with ending at B from starting at A, the amount of distance I travel will be less than if I walked by going along AD then to DB

Comment: Oh , I had changed pic in middle which made it wrong. I fixed it now @LinAlg

Comment: hmm how do I prove the steps commute? @LinAlg

Comment: I think the problem is that the type of 'step-2' depends on where exactly you are on the grid, because the vector pointly directly to B is position dependent